# sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-sbt-plugin;2.0: not found

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, typesafe

I'm having issues with sbt compile..

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-sbt-plugin;2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attri

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-sbt-plugin;2.0: not found
```

I'm running on sbt version 0.13.8 and Scala 2.11.4.

This is the build.sbt file

```
name := "test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaV = "2.3.14"
  val sprayV = "1.3.1"
  Seq (
"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.1",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"   % akkaV,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j"   % akkaV,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote"  % akkaV,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-agent"   % akkaV,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-sbt-plugn" % akkaV,
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaV % "test"
  )
}

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Spray repository" at "http://repo.spray.io",
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/",
  "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/",
  "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots"
)

Revolver.settings: Seq[sbt.Setting[_]]
```

And this is the plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.8.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-sbt-plugin" % "2.0")
```

I'm currently using intellij.
It was working fine with spray and joda-time, but started to having issues when akka was added.

Comment: See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.14/scala/microkernel.html - use addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0-RC1") for akka 2.3.14 instead of addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-sbt-plugin" % "2.0")

Answer (score 0):

The akka-sbt-plugin has ben removed as stated in the [Migration guide from 2.2 to 2.3](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0-RC1/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html)

It has been replaced by the [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) so you should take a look into using that.